# How to prevent Excel from doubling apostrophes?

Tags: c#, excel

I am programmatically generating an Excel file from C# and for some reason any single quotes are being doubled in the resulting cells in Excel. For example, `Foo's` becomes `Foo''s`. The single quote becomes two single quotes. Why is this and how to stop it?

The code simply reads in data from the DB and inserts it into cells/rows. The C# logic is irrelevant. I can do strCellData = strCellData.Replace("'", "x"); and it will display Fooxs just fine. Excel is doing something with the single quotes that is independent of the code.

I also confirmed that the data being read into the Excel file does not contain double single-quotes. Excel is manipulating the data.

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to post some code :)

Comment: The code simply reads in data from the DB and inserts it into cells/rows. The C# logic is irrelevant. I can do strCellData = strCellData.Replace("'", "x"); and it will display `Fooxs` just fine. Excel is doing something with the single quotes that is independent of the code.

Comment: "The code simply reads in data from the DB and inserts it into cells/rows" That doesn't sound "simple" to me...

Comment: 1. Run in in the debugger to see the input value and trace it through the steps.  2. Add the SQL query and the code that takes the values and put them in Excel to your question.

Comment: It's definitely not C# because strCellData.Contains("''") returns false.

Comment: sounds as you using `interop`. Use `OLEDb.ACE`. This is better way to fill `Excel` Files with data

Comment: It might be that Excel treats the apostrophe as a special escape sequence character (i.e. a character that has special meaning only to Excel). Have you tried replacing the single apostrophe with `"''"` or maybe `"\'"` before inserting it into the cell? Might be worth a try.

Comment: Thanks all for your suggestions. It looks like the string output of the C# code was returned and inserted into the DB, and the DB (or some other intermediate script) was escaping the single quotes. I resolved the issue by adding strCellData.Replace("'", "&#39;")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved by replacing the apostrophes/single quotes:

```
strCellData = strCellData.Replace("'", "&#39;");
```